# How to Combine Tkinter windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I have two groups of codes and the first part is a turtle graphics window and second part is a Tkinter window. How should I those two parts together to one window?

My first part of the code

```
from turtle import *

def move(thing, distance):
    thing.circle(250, distance)

def main():
    rocket = Turtle()
    ISS = Turtle()
    bgpic('space.gif')
    register_shape("ISSicon.gif")
    ISS.shape("ISSicon.gif")

    rocket.speed(10)
    ISS.speed(10)
    counter = 1
    title("ISS")
    screensize(750, 750)
    ISS.hideturtle()
    rocket.hideturtle()
    ISS.penup()
    ISS.left(90)
    ISS.fd(250)
    ISS.left(90)
    ISS.showturtle()
    ISS.pendown()
    rocket.penup()
    rocket.fd(250)
    rocket.left(90)
    rocket.showturtle()
    rocket.pendown()
    rocket.fillcolor("white")

    while counter == 1:
        move(ISS, 3)
        move(rocket, 4)

main()
```

Second part

```
from Tkinter import *

control=Tk()
control.title("Control")

control.geometry("200x550+100+50")
cline0=Label(text="").pack()
cline1=Label(text="Speed (km/s)").pack()

control.mainloop()
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uhm, I'm not sure if mixing them is a good idea. This `turtle` module frequently uses the  `update` command from Tcl, and this will very likely cause problems when more involved code is added in the mix (it is nice that apparently `turtle` can live with it). Anyway, one way to mix both is by using `RawTurtle` in place of `Turtle`, so you can pass your own `Canvas` which `turtle` will adjust for its needs.

Here is an example (I also replaced the infinite loop by an infinite re-schedule, basically):

```
import Tkinter
import turtle

def run_turtles(*args):
    for t, d in args:
        t.circle(250, d)
    root.after_idle(run_turtles, *args)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

frame = Tkinter.Frame(bg='black')
Tkinter.Label(frame, text=u'Hello', bg='grey', fg='white').pack(fill='x')
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(frame, width=750, height=750)
canvas.pack()
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

turtle1 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
turtle2 = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)

turtle1.ht(); turtle1.pu()
turtle1.left(90); turtle1.fd(250); turtle1.lt(90)
turtle1.st(); turtle1.pd()

turtle2.ht(); turtle2.pu()
turtle2.fd(250); turtle2.lt(90)
turtle2.st(); turtle2.pd()

root.deiconify()

run_turtles((turtle1, 3), (turtle2, 4))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks that is exactly what I want also, for the Tkinter.Label right now it has text "hello" in it, is it possible to replace that label by the position of turtle1, position of turtle2 and a timer(or the time from your computer)?(if that's not possible to put those variables in one line, three separated lines will be okay as well) thanks again ;)

Comment: I have seen people doing it with the entrybox but sadly I don't know the codes for that...

Comment: @user2006082 it is certainly possible, and it doesn't need an entry box for that. Just get the positions of the turtles and update the label's text to show it.

Comment: @user2006082 `mylabel['text'] = 'somenewtext'`