# Embedding turtle graphics in Pyqt5 interface

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make GUI in pyqt5 with only a button and a simple recursive drawing

what're the ideal tools for this task? 
I tried [Turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html) which is simple and get the job done but I don't know how to embed the graphics inside pyqt it opens a different window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turtle` is built on top of
[tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). `tkinter` and `pyqt5`
each use their own event loop. I don't think it is possible (or at least, it
wouldn't be very easy) to mix two different GUI toolkits (`tkinter` and `pyqt5`)
in one app.

If you want to use `turtle`, you should build the GUI with `tkinter` and [embed a `RawTurtle` in a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514923/190597).

Or, alternatively, build the GUI with `pyqt5`, and make the [drawing with, perhaps, a QPen](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/painting/).